Subfolder uploaded to the main folder of the project instead of the dir path indicated under 'Directory' input (github-push-action)
I'm trying to commit some files and folders to a subfolder of my main project, but all the documents end up in a pull request in the wrong location.
In some part of my workflow, I have this output:

Then, the commit & push part of the script shows the following:

This is the last part of the workflow script that I'm running:
      - name: Init new repo in dist folder and commit generated files
        run: |
          cd docs/build/html/
          git init
          touch .nojekyll
          git add -A
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git commit -m 'deploy'

      - name: Config global safe directory
        run: |
          git config --global --add safe.directory /github/workspace/docs/build/html

      - name: Force push to destination branch
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: rtd-pages
          force: true
          directory: './docs/build/html'

When I try to make the pull request, I see that all the files were pushed to the base directory instead of the expected /docs/build/html stated in the 'Directory' input:

Am I doing something wrong?
I've opened an Issue (#199) in Github because I consider I'm not, that by including the './docs/build/html' as a 'Directory' input it should work, but this is the first time I'm experimenting with Github actions.
Thanks in advance!
repository: https://github.com/matteemol/dbSketcher
workflow file: https://github.com/matteemol/dbSketcher/blob/main/.github/workflows/commit-doc-changes.yml

Solution: set force_with_lease: True instead of force: True, but most important is not to change to the docs/build/html/ directory before staging the changes.
I wasn't considering the very important fact that for git purposes, the name of each file consists of the PATH/NAME.ext and not only the NAME.ext.
E.g: by changing to the docs/build/html/ before staging, I was then pushing index.html instead of docs/build/html/index.html. The Directory directive moving to docs/build/html/ before pushing helped in not rising any error during the push. If this weren't present, I believe that the action would have failed, as it would have tried to push index.html from the main folder which didn't exist.
See the fully working workflow here:
or here:
``
name: Commit documentation changes (html)
on:

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:

  runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v5
      with:
        python-version: '3.9'

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: make the sphinx docs
      run: |
        make -C docs clean 
        make -C docs html

    - name: Init new repo in dist folder and commit generated files
      run: |
        touch .nojekyll
        git add -A
        git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
        git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
        git commit -m 'deploy'

    - name: Force push to destination branch
      uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        branch: rtd-docs
        force_with_lease: true``

